# Access properties of an "or"-typed object

Tags: typescript

how can i access the 'y' - attriubte in the following code?

```
export type AutogeneratedResult = {
  a: string
} | { a: string, b: string } | { y: string };

function foo(): AutogeneratedResult {
  return {
    y: 'test'
  }
}


const x = foo();

console.log(x.y);  // <---- Syntax error
```

I dont have a clue how i can fix this problem.

Typescript-Playground:
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcCCBXGEDmwB2wUAhjMACYBKwAzhgDbwC8cA3gFBxzEBccNMKAEt8OdgF84AHzbc+A4aIA0cAEbzBInHEkzWcRBsXbxAbnbsAZhnwBjGEIj44liBAAUASj6ZseQiRkVLQM8BxcUMAwGFDO4VwGfADkZAJJnDoSFuy2TgJwIHAsrh6e5jl5EPTAAHT0uO4gNYhlQA

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you know exactlyn what you are returning and then you returns the precise type :

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFgewJYGMIEEoF4oG8oCGAXFAM7ABOSAdgOZQC+A3AFCiSyKoQBC2ehEuSp0ANFABGQyjXrM24aPGRoY-fCGki5rFhAAeYBBWBR20dAFdgCWhGoQKBYBAAmAJQilLAG1M5lbkwAH04VXihQwNVdADNLahRgJARqKFiEBAAKAEoSaIg1XBYoKAoIYEsKNOLS0s0oAHIXckaSxlYGFhYUVPIofX4M7JzdXupSBB8IADofWyz9GZBRoA)

```
type ChoiceA = { a: string };
type ChoiceB = { a: string, b: string };
type ChoiceC = { y: string };

export type AutogeneratedResult = ChoiceA | ChoiceB | ChoiceC;

function foo(): ChoiceC {
  return {
    y: 'test'
  };
}

const x = foo();

console.log(x.y);
```

---

Either you have to check the return type :

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgFgewJYGMIEEoF4oG8oCGAXFAM7ABOSAdgOZQC+A3AFCiSyKoQBC2ehEuSp0ANFABGQyjXrM24aPGRoY-fCGki5rFhAAeYBBWBR20dAFdgCWhGoQKBYBAAmAJQilLAG1M5lbkwAH04VXihQwNVdADNLahRgJARqKFiEBAAKAEoSKxs7BycXDy9fU1wWKCgKCGBLCjSqmprNKAByF3IO6sZWBhYWFFTyKH1+DOyc3SRYqCyOkA6oGnGcvD6akepSBB8IADofWyz9Q5AZlgYgA)

```
type ChoiceA = { a: string };
type ChoiceB = { a: string, b: string };
type ChoiceC = { y: string };

export type AutogeneratedResult = ChoiceA | ChoiceB | ChoiceC;

function foo(): AutogeneratedResult {
  return {
    y: 'test'
  };
}

const x = foo();

if ('y' in x) {
    console.log(x.y);
}
```

Comment: Sadly i cannot change the types because the are generated.

Comment: If you cannot decide the type, only use the `if ('y' in x) {` or `x?.y`